# How to make product image inherit from category image

Tags: categories, woocommerce-offtopic, images, post-thumbnails

I'm planning on importing large amount of products and automatically assign them to certain product categories(in woocommerce).

I have 5 different categories and want for each product in each of those categories to inherit it's category image/thumbnail.

For example lets take category 't-shirt'. **I want all t-shirt category products to have same image as t-shirt category' image/thumbnail.**

Right now I edited file in woocommerce/templates/single-product/product-image. This line:

`$post_thumbnail_id = $product->get_image_id();` changed to this: `$post_thumbnail_id = get_woocommerce_term_meta( $cat->term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true );`

The problem is, it changes image only on the product page, and I want it to be changed everywhere(product page, category page, quick view).

If You could at least guide me where and what to change:)

Thank you. (I'm using Astra theme, just in case).

Comment: You'd have to duplicate your process on the templates that generate those other pages - in the WooCommerce documentation you can see a list of templates.  One thought though, what if a product has multiple categories?  How do you decide which image should be used?

Comment: Okay, thank you. But i get next problem, template file' code, which renders those products looks like this: `woocommerce_product_loop_start();

 if ( wc_get_loop_prop( 'total' ) ) {
  while ( have_posts() ) {
   the_post();
   do_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop' );
   wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );
  }
 }
 woocommerce_product_loop_end();` Where and/or how to find those files to edit?